# RStudio Server работает с одного клиента и не работает с другого

Tags: r, rstudio

Имеется 2 ноутбука с которых через web-интерфейс ведется работа с RStudio Server. 
При этом при работе с одного ноута приложение висит, при работе с другого ноута под той же учетной записью - никаких проблем, все работает. Причем проблема актуальна только для одной учетной записи. Для остальных проблем нет.
Есть предположение, что RStudio Server создает на локальной машине какую-то настроечную директорию, где на одной из машин сбились настройки.
Очистка кэша не помогла.
Перезапуск сервиса rstudio-server также не помог.

```
systemctl stop rstudio-server
killall -9 rstudio
systemctl restart rstudio-server
```

Информацию о версии RStudio Server прикладываю:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Answer (score 0):

В системе для каждого пользователя RStudio создаётся системная учётная запись. Одновременно под одной учётной записью с разных клиентов работать нельзя. Если проблема только с одной учётной записью, то можно попробовать удалить все относящиеся к RStudio конфигурационные файлы в домашней директории проблемной учётной записи.